# How to restore previous value of ng-select when confirmation return false?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular-ngselect

I have a branch selection dropdown list on the page. When the dropdown is selected something, I show a confirmation message that returns 'ok' and 'cancel'. When the message returns 'Cancel' i.e 'false', I don't want to update the selected value. How may I achieve that in Angular?

This is my component.html file

```
<ng-select [items]="data" bindLabel="BranchName" 
   bindValue="BranchID" 
   [clearable]='false' [(ngModel)]="selectedBranchId"
   [searchable]="false" 
  (change)="onBranchChange()">
</ng-select>
```

This is my current component.ts file

```
onBranchChange() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure to change branch?")) {
     //Do something
  }
  else{
     //Reset selected value of dropdown list to previous value
     this.selectedBranchId = previousValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
selectedBranchId: any;
tempSelectedBranchId: any;

onBranchChange(): void {
  if (confirm('Are you sure to change branch?')) {
    this.tempSelectedBranchId = this.selectedBranchId;
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectedBranchId = this.tempSelectedBranchId;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```